# Is there any tools to generate html with js chart to pdf?

Tags: python, d3.js, pdf-generation, report

I use d3 js to visualization my data,

and then I want to create a report which use the d3js chart and html generate a pdf file ,

any tools to use for this，such as  `python` script or other tools

Comment: Print from browser and export to PDF :)

Comment: Why the down votes? The question makes sense, especially if one wants to do that automatically from a Python script.

Comment: @arbautjc  yes i just want automatically from a Python script

Comment: @Jordan Jambazov if i can use some automatically tool to  do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at: http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart
Simply call the phantomjs script in your python script using [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)
It's pretty straight forward and easy to use